# Value of g(n) in Big O Notation

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

According to the definition of Big O notation, Let g and f be functions from the set of natural numbers to itself. The function f is said to be O(g), if there is a constant c and a natural n 0 such that f (n) ≤ cg(n) for all n > n0 .
So, if f(n) = O(n), can we say that g(n) = n ?

Comment: Yes; is there a reason you're unsure?

Comment: Will it be equal to n or we'll say that the highest order term in g(n) is n? I am doubtful regarding this.

Comment: In your definition, g is the function in the O(...) brackets, so in O(n), that function is just n.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your question is not well defined. Taking the question at face value, the answer is no: given `f ∈ O(n)`, of course we cannot say that `g(n) = n` because you haven't mentioned `g` in the antecedent of your hypothesis. You only mentioned `g` in the definition of `O`, but there is no link between the definition and your hypothesis.

So maybe you meant: *given `f ∈ O(n)` and `f ∈ O(g(n))`, does it follow that `g(n) = n`?* The answer is clearly no.

So maybe your question is more about notation: *is writing `O(n)` equivalent to writing `O(g)` where `g(n) = n`?* This is a more interesting question that I'll attempt to answer in a bit more detail.

First note that the O-notation is used in a way that is sloppy in various aspect which can lead to some confusion. The most obvious sloppiness comes from the fact that people often write `f = O(g)` to mean `f ∈ O(g)`. The confusion in your case may be at least partly due to a less often noticed sloppiness.

What is usually glossed over is that there are infinitely many different O-operators:

1. The O-operator takes a function as argument. In this case the O-operator is (implicitly) parameterized by the arity of the function. To make this explicit, we could write `O_1(g)` where `g(x) = x` or `O_2(f)` where `f(x,y) = x`. Note that in this example, `O_1(g)` and `O_2(f)` do not denote the same set, even though the function bodies are both `x`.
2. The O-operator takes a function body as argument. In this case the O-operator is (implicitly) parameterized by an ordered sequence of variable names and acts in a way similar to a lambda binding. To make this explicit, we could write `O_n(n)` or `O_{n,m}(n)`. Note again that these two are not equal. However, these equalities hold: `O_n(n) = O_1(g)` and `O_{n,m}(n) = O_2(f)`. Note also that the variable names can be alpha-renamed, so `O_n(n) = O_x(x) = O_y(y)`.

(Nobody usually spells these parameters out explicitly. But it helps to be aware of what is going on implicitly. For example, when people say something like "the complexity is not `O(E)` but `O(V)`" they are implicitly, and perhaps unknowingly, using a *dyadic* O-operator `O_{E,V}`, for otherwise the statement would be meaningless since `O_E(E) = O_V(V)`!)

So coming back to your question: if you write `O(n)`, then you *probably* mean `O_n(n)`, and if you write `O(g)`,  you *probably* mean `O_1(g)`. If so, then both are indeed equal. But note that `O_n(n)` is also equal to e.g. `O_1(h)` where `h(x) = 2x + 1`.

Hope you are not even more confused now!